# How to Change Mouse Cursor in PythonCard

Tags: python, user-interface, mouse, cursor, pythoncard

How do I change the mouse cursor to indicate a waiting state using Python and PythonCard?

I didn't see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PythonCard builds on top of wx, so if you import wx you should be able to build a suitable cursor (e.g. with `wx.CursorFromImage`), set it (e.g. with `wx.BeginBusyCursor`) when your wait begins, and end it (with `wx.EndBusyCursor`) when your wait ends.